# How to remove default right border radius of mui ToggleButton?

Tags: material-ui

How to change these default 0 to some other value(I am using [this](https://mui.com/components/toggle-button/#color) ToggleButton component )

```
.css-1gjgmky-MuiToggleButtonGroup-root .MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type) {
    border-top-right-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
}
```

I have tried

```
const StyledToggleButton = styled(ToggleButton)({
  borderBottomRightRadius: 4,  
  borderTopRightRadius: 4,
});
```

But this failed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

re your question's particular answer you can try following way.

```
const StyledToggleButton = styled(ToggleButton)({
  '&.MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped:not(:last-of-type)':{
        borderRadius: '4px !important',
      },
});
```

But my preferred way to display toggle buttons is below,

```
  <ToggleButton
    sx={{
      "&.MuiToggleButtonGroup-grouped": {
        borderRadius: "4px !important",
        mx: 1,
        border: "1px solid lightgrey !important"
      }
    }}
  >
    ...
  </ToggleButton>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your node module package go to the  @mui then material then tooglebuttongroup folder then you'll find ToggleButtonGroup.js file there you'll find the default settings you can change as per your desire. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gad2h.png)